# Keras custom layer not returning weights, unlike normal layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras-layer, tensorflow-layers

I am trying to get weights of the layer. It seems to work properly when keras layer is used and the input is connected to it.
However, while wrapping it into my custom layer, that does not work anymore. Is that a bug or what am I missing?

Edit: considerations:

I read that one can define in build() of custom layer the trainable variables. However, since custom layer consists of keras layer Dense (and potentially more keras layers later), those should already have defined trainable variables and weight/bias initializers. (I would not see a way to overwrite them, in **init**() of TestLayer, with variables that would be defined in build() of TestLayer.

```
class TestLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestLayer, self).__init__()
        self.test_nn = layers.Dense(3)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(TestLayer, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        test_out = test_nn(inputs) # which is test_in
        return test_out


test_in = layers.Input((2,))
test_nn = layers.Dense(3)
print(test_nn.get_weights()) # empty, since no connection to the layer
test_out = test_nn(test_in)
print(test_nn.get_weights()) # layer returns weights+biases

testLayer = TestLayer()
features = testLayer(test_in)
print(testLayer.get_weights()) # Problem: still empty, even though connected to input.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) says that `build()` method should have calls to `add_weight()` which you do not have:

> Should have the calls to add_weight(), and then call the super's build()

You also don't need to define a dense layer inside of your class if you are subclassing `layers.Layer`.
This is how you should subclass:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class TestLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, outshape=3):
        super(TestLayer, self).__init__()
        self.outshape = outshape

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(int(input_shape[1]), self.outshape),
                                      trainable=True)

        super(TestLayer, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)

test_in = layers.Input((2,))

testLayer = TestLayer()
features = testLayer(test_in)
print(testLayer.get_weights())
#[array([[-0.68516827, -0.01990592,  0.88364804],
#       [-0.459718  ,  0.19161093,  0.39982545]], dtype=float32)]
```

[Here](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) are some more examples of subclassing `Layer` class.

**However**, if you insist on implementing it your way and if you want to use `get_weights()` you have to override it (in this case you can just create a class without subclassing):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class TestLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, outshape=3):
        super(TestLayer, self).__init__()
        self.test_nn = layers.Dense(outshape)
        self.outshape = outshape

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(TestLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return self.test_nn(inputs)

    def get_weights(self):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run([x.initializer for x in self.test_nn.trainable_variables])
            return sess.run(self.test_nn.trainable_variables)

test_in = layers.Input((2,))

testLayer = TestLayer()
features = testLayer(test_in)
print(testLayer.get_weights())
#[array([[ 0.5692867 ,  0.726858  ,  0.37790012],
#       [ 0.2897135 , -0.7677493 , -0.58776844]], dtype=float32), #array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Thanks! One question is, how would the implementation then look like if I had  layers.BatchNormalization after Dense?  I guess own implementation within call() be necessary as well, but this one seems not straightforward. 
(I am wondering also if that is intended way for custom layers.)

Comment: The way you wrote it is not intended way to use custom layers. The intended way is the one that I provided and that is what official documentation states. But again, if you're not using it inside some keras object (e.g. `Sequential()`) that's will be fine. Otherwise you would have to override all required methods (`get_weights()` is one of them) to make it work. I really suggest you to go through tutorials on the official website. + I would you want to subclass BN? Do it only if you understand the implementation. It is not that trivial as `tf.matmul() + bias`.

Comment: `how would the implementation then look like if I had layers.BatchNormalization after Dense?` - like this: ` bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(features)`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, using Layers inside other Layers is not supported in Keras. 
I have encountered the problem in the past, and opened an issue [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11736), but the team confirmed to me that this is intentional.

You can either define a method in your custom layer like:

```
def dense(X, f_in, f_out):
    W = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                        shape=(f_in, f_out))
    b = self.add_weight(name='bias',
                        shape=(f_out, ))
    return K.dot(X, W) + b
```

or subclass the Dense layer and use the output of `super().call()`.